# Overlay background image in ng-image-slider

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to apply a watermark(with an image) to an image inside a carousel. I replaced my previous `ngx-bootrap/carousel` by [ng-image-slider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-image-slider). In my previous code, I use this and it works fine:

```css
.watermarked:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-image: url("/assets/images/confidential.png");
  background-size: 300px 300px;
  background-repeat: space;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Now, I find the container in the `DOM` and located the classs to override the css by my custom watermark css (is what the author recommends):

```css
ng-image-slider .ng-image-fullscreen-view .custom-image-main img {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-image: url('/assets/images/confidential.png');
  background-size: 300px 300px;
  background-repeat: space;
  opacity: 0.9;
  border: 3px solid orange;
}
```

It 'works', because while the image is loading, I can see the background with my image, but after the load, it disappears..

While loading:

[image: While loading]

After the image load, the background get covered and I cannot see anything:

[image: After load]

Is this a normal behaviour? Is possible to maintain the background in the front line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use `::after` in your example code. Add that to the container of the image since `::after` doesn't work on `img`. I would suggest the following, but make sure that either `.custom-image-main` or another parent in your slider has `position: relative;` or the absolute positioning  won't work.

```
.ng-image-slider .ng-image-fullscreen-view .custom-image-main::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-image: url('/assets/images/confidential.png');

  ...etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! With ```::after``` and ```z-index```, you save my day!